# Trouble importing both JButton and JFrame with MouseListeners

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, mouselistener, mousemotionlistener

I'm making a paint program, which needs to implement both `MouseMotionListener` and `MouseListener`.  It also needs `javax.swing.JFrame` and `javax.swing.JButton`.

If I import either `JFrame` or `JButton` by themselves, there is no compile error (besides that buttons/frames won't be understood).  However, if I import both, I get an error in the dual implementing of `MouseListener` and `MouseMotionListener`.

The error received is:

```
MyPaint is not abstract and does not override abstract method 
    mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent) in java.awt.event.MouseListener
```

Importing `javax.swing.*;` does not solve the problem, and I am at a loss.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;



public class MyPaint extends Canvas implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
{
    public boolean bg;

    public static JButton brushSize1 = new JButton("Size 1");
    public static JButton brushSize2 = new JButton("Size 2");
    public static JButton brushSize3 = new JButton("Size 3");

    //all the code necessary
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example). 2) Always copy/paste error and exception output!

Comment: `public static JButton brushSize1 = new JButton("Size 1");`  BTW 1) When it comes to GUI elements, `static` is not our friend. 2) Those 3 buttons should probably be one `JComboBox` or (better) a `JSpinner` with spinner number model. 3) For a `JButton` it is better to add an `ActionListener` that will react to mouse clicks as well as the keyboard.

Comment: Did we forget to implement the requirements of the interface contract...also why are you extending from `Canvas`, mixing heavy and light weight components is not a good idea

Comment: I apologize @HovercraftFullOfEels , the error I get is "className is not abstract and does not override abstract method mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent) in java.awt.event.MouseListener"

Comment: I assume you understand what an `interface` is and how they work?  You might like to have a read through [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) for some more details

Comment: *"Importing `javax.swing.*;` does not solve the problem"*  Why would you think it would?  It really seems like you are trying 'coding by magic' and that never works well.  It is necessary to try and understand what the compiler errors are telling you.  In this case, they mean the code declares implementation of an interface - yet does not *actually* implement all the necessary methods defined in the interface.

Answer (score 2):

```
MyPaint is not abstract and does not override abstract method 
    mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent) in java.awt.event.MouseListener
```

This means the code declares implementation of an interface - yet does not *actually* implement all the methods defined in the interface.  To get rid of that error, define the method!

Answer (score 0):

**MouseListener** and **MouseMotionListener** both are **interfaces**. So, if you are implementing them, then you will have to define all the methods in the interface. Like This:

```
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){
    // Do what you want to do with this.
}
```

Like this, you will have to define **ALL** the methods in the interface.